# How can I split a comma separated variable?

Tags: jquery

I have a function that gives me some data output:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
    table.MakeCellsEditable({
        "onUpdate": myCallbackFunction
    });
});

function myCallbackFunction(updatedCell, updatedRow, oldValue,row) {
     console.log("The values for each cell in that row are: " + updatedRow.data());
}
```

My console output is: `The values for each cell in that row are:   2,Alan,Dirt,Joe@example.com`

I want now to output inside my function only the first value of the comma separated list. So I changed it to the following:

```
 function myCallbackFunction(updatedCell, updatedRow, oldValue,row) {
       var row = updatedRow.data();
       var id = row.split(","); 
         console.log("The first value is: " + id[0]);
    }
```

But I get the console error now `TypeError: row.split is not a function. (In 'row.split(",")', 'row.split' is undefined)`

What does this mean?

Comment: which version of jquery referred

Comment: @BalajiM the version is 2.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `updatedRow.data();` must already be an array.

Just use the following:

```
function myCallbackFunction(updatedCell, updatedRow, oldValue,row) {
   var row = updatedRow.data(); // this is array already
   console.log("The first value is: " + row[0]);
}
```

How I'm sure that `row` is an Array?
If you do the following,

```
var data = ["my", "world"];
console.log("Hello " + data);
```

the output will be `Hello my,world`. The same as in your example.

So you can directly use `data[0]` as it's already an array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the data to string like this

```
var row = updatedRow.data().toString();
```

Comment: It's a wrong hack. `updatedRow.data()` is already an array. Why convert it to string and then split to make it array again?

You can use `updatedRow.data()[0]`